# How to choose a magnetic field $B$ for Schrodinger equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, physics, mathematical-physics

I am now solving a Schrodinger equation with a magnetic field:
$$i\hbar U_{t}-V(x)U-0.5\left(\frac{\hbar}{i}-B(x)\right)^2U=0$$
where $V$ is a real and smooth potential and $B$ is the magnetic field which has to satisfy Gauss' law: $$\nabla \cdot B=0.$$

By now, I have tried $$B=\text{constant}$$ and $$B=\cos(\vec{k} \cdot \vec{x}-kct),$$ but the result is weird when comparing to the graph of the original equation ($B=0$).

I don't know what the solution is supposed to look like when adding different $B$ and I am wondering if I should use some other magnetic field.

Comment: For guidance on the constant field case see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_quantization .